# Passing functions to R with f(myclass.myfunc) syntax

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am new to R. I have googled my problem but found nothing addressing exactly what I'm looking for. I know you can pass functions into other functions, but I would like to pass an "object" like variable into a function with other functions bound to the 'object'. Here is what I mean

```
model1.calculation1 = function() {
    print( "model1.calculation1" )
}
model2.caclulation1 = function() {
    print( "model2.calculation2" ) 
}

runModel = function( model ) {
    model.calculation1() 
}
runModel( model1 )
runModel( model2 )
```

and the error message:

```
Error in model.calculation1() : 
  could not find function "model.calculation1"
```

Note I am not doing anything to instantiate any model1 or model2 before binding a function to them. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Typo error. Check spelling.... you want: `model1.calculation1() `

Comment: No, I would like ```runModel``` to call ```calculation1```  on the model that I pass as parameter.

Comment: Thanks Edward, but I don't have a typo. The reason I am calling ```model.caclulation1()``` and not ```model1.calculation1()``` is because model is the function parameter name of ```runModel```. I would like ```runModel``` to call ```calculation1``` on whatever model I pass to it as its parameters.

Comment: This is something I would do in javascript and aware R is its own thing all together, so I was wondering if I could achieve this with similar syntax or if I need to resort to classes and what not.

Comment: Fair enough, but the error is still throwing in ```  could not find function "model.calculation1"``` and fixing the typo and rerunning  did still gave the same error.

Comment: Yes, something like this is exactly what I'm looking for. Upvoted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `substitute`.

```
runModel = function( model ) {
  s <- substitute(model)
  if(s=="model1")
    model1.calculation1() 
  else
    model2.calculation1() 
}

runModel( model1 )
# [1] "model1.calculation1"

runModel( model2 )
# [1] "model2.calculation2"
```

---

```
model1 <- lm(mpg~hp, data=mtcars)
model2 <- lm(mpg~hp+am, data=mtcars)
```